# SSRS: Deployed reporting path. How to delete strange duplicated folder by space

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have uploaded a report to Microsoft Reporting Services (SSRS) with the TargetReportFolder path with a %20 values instead of space char.

Due to that, I have now two folders in my SSRS with the same subfolders and files. The difference is that the name of one has space and the other %20 (Say one folder being "Elephant zoo" and the other "Elephant%20Zoo".

I want to delete "Elephant%20Zoo" but I and fearful that if I do that I remove all the other folder content. Because weirdly, the content is the same and if I try to administrate the "Elephant%20Zoo" folder it sends me to "Elephant zoo" administration.

Comment: I've not come across this, you could check the dbo.catalog table and see what paths are shown for reports that are in those folders. You could also try renaming the *bad* one directly in the catalog table (**just the name**)and see if it affects anything, if not then it's probably safe to delete the *bad* one.

Comment: Thanks, i checked in dbo.catalog and hide the misnamed folder. Now works fine.

Renaming doesnt work directly in the browser.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. When I talked about renaming. I meant rename the folder directly in the catalog table, just the `Name` column. You should then be able to differentiate the two folder clearly and be able to delete the bad one.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alan Schofield suggested going through SQLServer database works. The folder is a row in dbo.catalog table. I changed the value of hide from 0 to 1 and now the folder is hidden and doesnt make any issue in SSRS on browser.